# Archiving Historical Data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, delete

Right now on Production, for deleting historical data, used a script which is manually run in SSMS.
Script deletes batches of 100 rows from Table1 where [Date] between [Start] and [End] in a looped cycle

Table1 (ID column) is referenced by foreign keys from ~ 20 other tables with cascade rule, so when you delete from Table1, rows deleted from other tables as well

Script is a bit more complex than that, doing couple of additional calculations, and printing progress messages, but that does not affect performance.
Execution plan of delete statement itself is good.
Temp Table is used to hold batch of rows to delete (IDs)

- if increase batch size to 150, then one of the referencing tables (by FK) gets table-level Exclusive lock during delete, which reduces concurrency.
  100 rows per batch works just fine, no escalation
- interval between batches is 1 second. If changed to 0.5 sec, reporting async replica starts to fall behind more and more, I can see this in AG dashboard.
  Not that is is critical, but reports need fresh data

Above approach takes days to complete, as there are millions of rows for months that need to be deleted.
Process must be monitored for performance, as there are other apps querying data and sometimes deleting process may interfere with those apps, so can't leave deletion process fully autonomous.
Add time it takes to reorganize index afterwards, to regain some of the space which has not been released after deletion (it is seen as "unused" in sp_spaceused, but still as part of the table)

Previous years are saved to reporting replica as Prod_2021, Prod_2020 databases and backups

**Question:**

Are there any other - better and / or less time consuming way(s) to perform archiving of historical data ?

I've read about Partitioning (table / index) although have never used it.
Heard there can be performance issues with it and it's administration is cumbersome ?
Is it true, and this technology must be avoided, or it is worth to be implemented ?

Any other ways to archive / delete old data other than "deleting in batches" (described above) and "Partitioning" ?

Comment: Have you reviewed [Aaron's](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes) and [Michael's](https://michaeljswart.com/2014/09/take-care-when-scripting-batches/) tips for delete batches?

Comment: You can consider using SSIS too.

Comment: @Learning_DBAdmin can't get down-time, using AG for a reason